# Boxplot for more than two depedent variables on one graph

Tags: boxplot, manova

How do I have a boxplot for three or more dependent variables on one graph with the ANOVA significance letter?
For example, I have the following data set:

---

:Treatment  :Replication    :Feed_intake    :Body_weight Milk_yield
Maize          1            23       233         22
Sorghum        1            32       231         23
Wheat          1            34       323         22
Maize          2            12       342         12
Sorghum        2            23       122         32
Wheat          2            14       323         23

So how I can have the three dependent variables (Feed_intake, Body_weight, and Milk_yield) boxplot with their ANOVA significance letter on one graph?